# Вывод сложного меню с помощью массива

Tags: массивы, php

Добрый день!

Вот само меню **http://jsfiddle.net/a75GY/2/**

**Решил сделать по другому:**

*Старое все удалил от сюда, ниже комментарии не соответствуют новой идее.*

```
// получение массива каталога
$categories = get_cat();
$categories_tree = map_tree($categories);
$categories_menu = categories_to_string($categories_tree);

/**
* Получение массива категорий
**/
function get_cat(){
    global $connection;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM brands";
    $res = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    $arr_cat = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $arr_cat[$row['brand_id']] = $row;
    }
    return $arr_cat;
}

/**
* Построение дерева
**/
function map_tree($dataset) {
    $tree = array();

    foreach ($dataset as $brand_id=>&$node) {    
        if (!$node['parent_id']){
            $tree[$brand_id] = &$node;
        }else{ 
            $dataset[$node['parent_id']]['childs'][$brand_id] = &$node;
        }
    }

    return $tree;
}

/**
* Дерево в строку HTML
**/
function categories_to_string($data){
    foreach($data as $item){
        $string .= categories_to_template($item);
    }
    return $string;
}

/**
* Шаблон вывода категорий
**/
function categories_to_template($category){
    ob_start();
    include 'category_template.php';
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Вот файл **category_template.php**:

```
<li class="yyy">
    <a href="?category=<?=$category['brand_id']?>"><?=$category['brand_name']?></a>
    <?php if($category['childs']): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php echo categories_to_string($category['childs']); ?>
    </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
</li>
<span class="hr-emule"></span>
```

**И, наконец, результат:**

```
<ul id="mega-3" class="mega-menu">
   <h2 class="kat">Категории товаров</h2>
      <?php echo $categories_menu ?>
</ul>
```

Допустим у меня может быть высота выпадающего списка больше в каких то главных категориях, где parent = 0, это связано с тем что может быть больше вложенности (это class="yyy"), можно ли как-то применить другой class для какого-то нужного parent = 0.

Comment: Есть у кого какие мысли?

Comment: Что вы подаете на входе? Значение переменной $result в студию.

Comment: @Breaker, $result = get_cat();

Comment: Вы гениальны! Скажем по-другому: результат выполнения get_cat() в студию.

Comment: [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: @DimasikYES, Наберите:
    $result = get_cat();
    print_r($result);
И напишите сюда, что получилось.

Comment: @Breaker, Посмотри пожалуйста, переделал.

Comment: @DimasikYES, и всё-таки, я считаю, что на сайтах типа хэшкода или стаковерфлоу предпочтительнее задавать вопросы по языку, чем вопросы по реализации конкретной логики

Comment: @Dazar, может лучше какая идея есть по моим вопросам ?